# Understanding class OxfordPets in keras example

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

What is this line of code doing?

```py
x = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + self.img_size + (3,), dtype="float32")
```

Why is it adding up batch size, image size and 3 to get the shape of x? Shouldn't it multiply them?

The line is from the method `__getitem__` in the class `OxfordPets`. This is in the keras example described in https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/

The class code is:

```py
class OxfordPets(keras.utils.Sequence):
    """Helper to iterate over the data (as Numpy arrays)."""

    def __init__(self, batch_size, img_size, input_img_paths, target_img_paths):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.img_size = img_size
        self.input_img_paths = input_img_paths
        self.target_img_paths = target_img_paths

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.target_img_paths) // self.batch_size

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        """Returns tuple (input, target) correspond to batch #idx."""
        i = idx * self.batch_size
        batch_input_img_paths = self.input_img_paths[i : i + self.batch_size]
        batch_target_img_paths = self.target_img_paths[i : i + self.batch_size]
        x = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + self.img_size + (3,), dtype="float32")
        for j, path in enumerate(batch_input_img_paths):
            img = load_img(path, target_size=self.img_size)
            x[j] = img
        y = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + self.img_size + (1,), dtype="uint8")
        for j, path in enumerate(batch_target_img_paths):
            img = load_img(path, target_size=self.img_size, color_mode="grayscale")
            y[j] = np.expand_dims(img, 2)
            # Ground truth labels are 1, 2, 3. Subtract one to make them 0, 1, 2:
            y[j] -= 1
        return x, y
```